# Angular JS Login Form Login Method Not Called

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning angular and observing below behaviour and I am not able to understand the root cause behind this.

**app.js :**

```
angular.module('rolb', ['ngRoute']).config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'home.html',
        controller : 'homeController',
        controllerAs: 'homeController'
    }).when('/login', {
        templateUrl : 'login.html',
        controller : 'navigationController',
        controllerAs: 'navigationController'
    }).when('/subscribeConfirm', {
        templateUrl : 'subscribe.html',
        controller : 'subscriptionController',
        controllerAs: 'subscriptionController'
    }).otherwise('/');

   $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
   $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};
   $httpProvider.defaults.headers.put = {};
   $httpProvider.defaults.headers.patch = {};
   /*if this is not set , after successfull authentication for first time , the next request doesn't contain JSESSIONID and hence session is not established 
   requiring again /login request*/
   $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;

})
```

Simple module with routes defined

**Login.html :**

```
<form role="form" ng-submit="navigationController.login()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username:</label> <input type="text"
            class="form-control" id="username" name="username" ng-model="navigationController.credentials.username"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password:</label> <input type="password"
            class="form-control" id="password" name="password" ng-model="navigationController.credentials.password"/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**index.html :**

```
<body ng-app="rolb" ng-cloak class="ng-cloak">
    <div class="container">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#/">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/login">login</a></li>
            <li ng-show="authenticated"><a href="" ng-click="logout()">logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div ng-view class="container"></div>
    <script src="js/angular-bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/homeController.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

The issue is :

1)When I specify `ng-submit="navigationController.login()` the login method is called on NavigationController.

2)But when I specify , `ng-submit="login()"` , the login method is not called.

Queries  :

1)Since I have already defined routes in `app.js` which states that `login.html` should be attached to `NavigationController` , why I am need to specify `navigationController` before `login` method call ?

2)I have verified that as per `index.html` , `app.js` is getting loaded successfully in browser

**EDIT 1 :** 
Alongwith answer given below , I also modified function definition in NavigationController to append $scope like below :

**NavigationController.js**

```
$scope.login = function() {

        $http.post('http://localhost:8080/springbootrest/login', "username=" + encodeURIComponent(credentials.username) +
             "&password=" + encodeURIComponent(credentials.password), {
          headers : {
            "content-type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
          }
        }).success(function(data) {
            authenticate(function() {
                if ($rootScope.authenticated) {
                  $location.path("/");
                  $scope.loginError = false;
                } else {
                  $location.path("/login");
                  $scope.loginError = true;
                }
              });
            }).error(function(data) {
              $location.path("/login");
              $scope.loginError = true;
              $rootScope.authenticated = false;
            })
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have defined **[`controllerAs`](https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/)** in your route config, so in Template you need to defined the corresponding controller as syntax. Otherwise remove it from the config.

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'home.html',
        controller : 'homeController',
//remove controllerAs: 'homeController'
}).when('/login', {
        templateUrl : 'login.html',
        controller : 'navigationController',
//remove controllerAs: 'navigationController'
    }).when('/subscribeConfirm', {
        templateUrl : 'subscribe.html',
        controller : 'subscriptionController',
//remove controllerAs: 'subscriptionController'
 }).otherwise('/');
```

Comment: Thanks . In addition to above fix , I also modified NavigationController to append $scope before function definition.